# Get list item version history in SharePoint 2016 provider hosted app

Tags: csom, sharepoint-apps, sharepoint-2016

I have a provider hosted app and i want to retrieve the list item version history with all the columns of an item in my provider hosted app using CSOM. 
I tried using CAML Query but i am not able to achieve the required functionality.
Any pointer will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When loading file, use lambda expression to explicitly request all required attributes.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = context.Web.GetFileByUrl("URL_of_FILE"); //Can be referenced however you want
context.Load(file, x=>x.ListItemAllFields, x=>x.Versions);


//Execute query to reference attributes
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

To reference specific column values:

```
string columnVal= file.ListItemAllFields["col_val_id"].ToString();
```

Comment: this is for file, not for list item. OP asked specifically for list item